# The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "Scripts" Login/Register

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

so I have this weird problem, and honestly I have no clue when it stopped working, so it's hard for me to understand where's the problem. Basically, the login and register buttons stopped working, and I have no clue why.
From reading the error I understand that the problem is somewhere in the _Layout.cshtml, because I didn't touch the _LoginPartial.cshtml or any other related files in that matter.
Here's my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Guitar Store</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Guitar Store", "List", "Product", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.Action("Summary", "Cart")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <div class="row panel">
        <div id="categories" class="col-lg-3">
            @Html.Action("Menu", "Nav")
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-7">@RenderBody()</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please guide me to fixing that problem?

Edit: If any more files are needed I can edit them inside here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out what the problem was. I removed

`@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)`

from the _Layout.cshtml body. Apparently you have to have that in order for the login and register to work.